# ServerManager is throwing error when connecting to a remote full IIS server (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, visual-studio-2013

Same code works fine under Visual Studio 2012 using VS Development Server option. Since VS2013 no longer have this option, I am forced to use the IISExpress server option. The error that is being thrown is:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID
>   {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine MachineName failed
>   due to the following error: 80040154 MachineName.

And here's my code:

```
using (ServerManager sm = ServerManager.OpenRemote(remoteMachineName))
{
    foreach (Site site in sm.Sites)
    {
        // some code...
    }
}
```

I am using version 7.0.0.0 of Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll. The remote machine has only full IIS 7.5. Since my code is running under IISExpress in Visual Studio 2013, I suspect that it's trying to connect to IISExpress in the remote machine which is not installed, hence, the error COM not found.

Anyone encountered this before and found a fix?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem, I had to install IIS on my development machine and change the project setting under Project Properties --> Web -> Servers --> from IIS Express to Local IIS.

Also, make sure to register .net 4

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

Comment: That works if you are using a web api, but I still have a problem when I run this code from a console app